# overloading double subscript operator [][] in c++

Tags: c++, double, overloading, operator-keyword

how can I overload double subscript operator [][] in c++ ?

I have tried a number of ways.. No specific answer is available anywhere..

thanks in advance..

I have tried this.. But I know its not correct

```
class Matrix {

    int row;
    int col;
    int ** values;
    int ptr;

    public:
        Matrix(const int r, const int c) {

            ptr = -1;
            row = r;
            col = c;

            values = new int*[row];

            for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {

                values[i] = new int[col];
            }
        }

        int & operator[](int p) {

            if(ptr == -1)
                ptr = p;

            return values[ptr][p];

        }

};
```

Comment: There's no thing like a double subscript `operator [][]`.

Answer (score 5):

> double subscript operator `[][]`

There isn't a double-subscript operator in C++. What you can do is overload `operator[]` to return an object that also overloads `operator[]`. This will enable you to write `m[i][j]`.

Comment: thank u very much.. that was precise and clear..